# Flutter Video Player

Tags: flutter

I wanted a flutter app, which downloads video from the network and stores it in local memory. Video stored in local memory should not be accessible by other media players. Those videos should only be shown by my apps video player. Is it possible to do it in flutter?

Comment: Not a mobile dev expert, but does not [`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html) from [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) return the application's sandboxed directory unavailable to other apps? (Unless the device is rooted/jailbroken)

Answer (score 0):

you can store video in application directory, other apps cannot access it

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;

final directory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```